# Time taken by a reworked product- Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am building a fairly simple model to record the time taken by a product to be manufactured.

Need any guidance on how to segregate "virgin products" from "rework products".
I have around 4 rework loops. The product might visit either one or all four rework loops. I am not sure on how I can classify any "agent" that enters a rework loop in anylogic. I can measure individual rework times per block, but unable to classify an overview of how many agents entered rework as a whole and how many did not. I am using a DES approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn your products into individual agents that flow through the DES flow. Then, you can access each individual product and flag it as "reworked", log individual times...

Suggest you check out a few DES example models, most use agents to flow through the blocks, so you can see how it is done.

btw, this is one of the most powerful features of AnyLogic that competitors cannot compare with in terms of flexibility, so worth learning :-)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for the advise. If possible could you direct me to any resource to find such examples. I have scanned Anylogic libraries but I am unable to trace a similar logic.